# Intuition about a logic equivalence

Tags: logic

It is fairly easy to show that $(P\wedge Q)\to R$ is equivalent to $(P\to R)\lor(Q\to R)$.

However I am having trouble having an intuition about this equivalence. My intuition is that if both hypotheses $P$  and $Q$ are required to prove $R$, neither one by itself is sufficient to prove $R$.

Example 1: If I am very talented at basketball ($P$) and I am a man (Q) then I have a chance to play in NBA ($R$).

Example 2: If $p>2$ and $p$ is prime then $p$ is odd. However neither hypotheses by themselves imply that $p$ is an odd number.

Certainly my intuition is very wrong, could anyone give me perhaps more insight?

Comment: I would love to see a detailed answer to this. Here are my two cents:
1. Logical implication does not always correspond to our intuitive understanding of causation. Try searching "Paradoxes of Material Implication". 
2. Note that if you have $(P\to R)\vee (Q\to R)$, you still need both $P$ and $Q$ to deduce $R$, since you don't know which of the conditionals $P\to R$ or $Q\to R$ is true. If you have both, then you can conclude $R$, which you already knew.

Comment: Long story short: Implication is always unintuitive with a false premise.

Comment: Perhaps this relates to the erroneous habit of reading the material conditional, 'if A, then B', as the implication 'A implies B'.

Comment: The issue is not with the case $P \land Q$ *true* (that means **both** $P, Q$ *true*), but when it is *false*; see @bof's answer.

Comment: @Reveillark Thanks for the link to Material implication, was very good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The confusion here isn't with implication, but with your implicit use of a universal quantifier.

Look at your Example 2, but write out the quantifier (I'll assume that quantifiers are taken to quantify over the natural numbers):

$$(\forall p)\big((p\gt 2 \,\wedge\, p\text{ is prime}) \to p\text{ is odd}\big). \tag{1}$$

This means that every natural number that is both greater than 2 and prime is, in fact, odd.  (This is true, of course.)

By your propositional logic equivalence, it's correct to say that (1) is equivalent to:

$$(\forall p)\big((p\gt 2 \to p\text{ is odd}) \lor (p\text{ is prime }\to \;p\text{ is odd})\big),\tag{2}$$

although (2) is a strange, hard-to-interpret statement that nobody would write in that way.

This is *not*, however, equivalent to:

$$\big((\forall p)(p\gt 2 \to p\text{ is odd})\big)\lor\big((\forall p)(p\text{ is prime} \to p\text{ is odd})\big)\tag{3}$$

nor is it equivalent to

$$(\forall p)\big((p\gt 2 \,\lor\, p\text{ is prime} )\to p\text{ is odd})\big).\tag{4}$$

(3) means: Either (a) every natural number greater than 2 is odd or (b) every prime number is odd (or both).

(4) means: Every natural number that is either greater than 2 or prime (or both) is odd.

Both (3) and (4) are false — and, more to the point, they clearly aren't equivalent to (1) and to (2), nor does the propositional logic equivalence say that they should be.

---

So, in propositional calculus it's true that $(P\wedge Q)\to R$ is equivalent to $(P\to R)\lor(Q\to R),$ and it's therefore true in first-order logic that

$$(\forall x)\big((P(x) \wedge Q(x))\to R(x)\big)$$

is equivalent to

$$(\forall x)\big((P(x)\to R(x))\lor(Q(x)\to R(x)) \big).$$

But this isn't equivalent to
$$(\forall x)\big(P(x)\to R(x)\big) \lor (\forall x)\big(Q(x)\to R(x)\big),$$
for example.  In general, $(\forall x)(A(x)\lor B(x))$ isn't equivalent to $(\forall x)A(x) \lor (\forall x)B(x).$

Comment: I think your explanation is spot on for the second example, but I am not that convinced if it is the same for the first. Why should the statement "I am talented at basketball" be quantified as "For any person, if he is talented....."? This should be a statement in itself. I think that in this situation the lack of intuition has to do with the  the classical logic definition of "if.... then...." versus the natural language understanding of "if...then...".

Comment: Your example and the wikipedia article on Paradoxes of Material implication (https://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication) were both illuminating and clarified the issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking that in your Example 1, although you say "I", most people would interpret it to mean that it's not dependent on anything else about you besides the specific properties that you're specifying.  In other words, it means that every person who is both talented at basketball and is a man has a chance to play in the NBA.  So you're back in the same quantified situation as before.  (This may not be quite as clear as Example 2, since it depends on one's interpretation of the English sentence, but I think that's how most people would take it.)

Answer (score 5):

[Mitchell Spector's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939029/intuition-about-a-logic-equivalence/1939114#1939114) explained very well what's wrong with your examples. Let me try to explain *intuitively* why $(P\land Q)\to R$ is equivalent to $(P\to R)\lor(Q\to R).$ (Since this is an *intuitive* explanation, I feel absolved from any need to be rigorous or correct.)

Let me identify a proposition with its truth value, i.e., $P=1$ if $P$ is true, $P=0$ if $P$ is false. Then $P\to R$ is true just in case $P\le R,$ i.e., "$R$ is at least as true as $P$ is." Since $P\land Q=\min(P,Q),$ the equivalence
$$(P\land Q)\to R\iff(P\to R)\lor(Q\to R)$$
just says that
$$\min(P,Q)\le R\iff P\le R\text{ or }Q\le R$$
which is a simple arithmetical fact, nothing unintuitive about it.

Comment: Would you interpret "p or q" as max(p, q) or some other way?

Comment: That is very nice indeed,  thank you!

Comment: Yes, the $p\lor q$ is the $\max(p,q)$. Just replace the truth value by $0$ and $1$, as bof did, and you will see the truth table for $\lor$ is exactly the max.